# PHP instantiate class in main program, access from functions

Tags: php, object, scope

I've got a headache from reading about singletons and patterns and there must be a simpler way...

I have a nice utility function called log_it($severity,$message) that is used throughout a number of programs.  It creates code to append application specific log entries to a shared log on disk.  When I load the function once globally (using require) it is available throughout a program, in any function.

I'm converting the application as a whole to object-orientation for various good reasons.
I'd like to create a logger class that has a log_it($severity,$message) method.

I'd like to create the object once, in global scope, and use it from within functions.
I'd rather not have to declare the object as global within every function where i want to use it.  In other words I want to emulate the global visibility of the simple non-object function but using a class.  What I'd like to do is have $log=new logger() in the main program and then call $log->log_it() from anywhere without any further ado.

Hopefully there is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `log_it` as an static method. And call it from any place u want without needing to instantate the class. like so:

```
logger::log_it()
```

Comment: Thanks for that info Rahim.  Is there an advantage to using a statically declared class in this way vs. simply including the code via a require?